# Second Day in RoR, Having Trouble with Running Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I'm running on Lion, 10.7.3, with Ruby version 1.9.3-p125 and the latest version of Xcode.

When I attempt to start my server, I get the following error:

> Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.1.0) ruby' in the gems available on
>   this machine. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

So I attempted running bundle install and received the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":   In
snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    actionpack (3.1.0.rc4)   In Gemfile:
    meta_search (= 1.1.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using
only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I then attempted to run bundle update, but received the following error:

> An error occured while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

I've been totally stuck for a few hours now... Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is you can not install gem `mysql2`. What you got when running `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'`?

Comment: I received the following error: "Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options." So I checked the log and found this: 1 error generated. checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: /*top*/
4: int main() {return 0;}
5: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))mysql_query; return 0; }
/* end */

Comment: Problem solved: brew install mysql. Updated and reinstalled bundle and server is now working.

Comment: You might want to add your solution as answer and accept it to close this question.

Comment: What did you update? Homebrew? Bundler?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: brew install mysql. Updated and reinstalled bundle and server is now working.